# How to determine correct format of input parameters of a WSDL operation

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I'm very, very new to all the SOAP/WSDL thingy, so I must be asking something very basic or not using the correct technical terms. Please excuse me if that's the case.

I was provided a WSDL url by a colleague and I need to call that webservice using nuSOAP library.

He also gave me an XML - and I have no clue what to do with it

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://oracle.com/determinations/server/12.2.1/rulebase/assess/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:assess-request>
         <typ:global-instance>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <typ:attribute id="transaction_Amount" outcome-style="value-only"/>
             <typ:attribute id="line_Items" outcome-style="value-only"/>
             <typ:attribute id="requred_Documents" outcome-style="value-only"/>
            <typ:attribute id="transaction_Type">
               <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 8 items at this level-->
               <typ:text-val>Address Change</typ:text-val>
            </typ:attribute>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

         </typ:global-instance>
      </typ:assess-request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After researching for a while, I found that it has got something to do with "operation" and input parameters. So I build up a piece of code which looks something like this:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($url, "wsdl");
$error  = $client->getError();       
// I do not see the below message so I assume the connection was a success
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}
$params = array(
    'global-instance' => "attribute"
);

$result = $client->call("Assess", array("assess-request"=>$params));
if ($client->fault) {
  echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} else {
  $error = $client->getError();
  if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
  } else {
    echo "<h2>Main</h2>";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get

```
Array
(
    [faultcode] => SOAP-ENV:Client
    [faultstring] => Invalid element. Expected: global-instance. Actual: 
    [detail] => Array
        (
            [error-response] => Array
                (
                    [code] => com.oracle.determinations.server.exceptions.InvalidRequestException
                    [message] => Invalid element. Expected: global-instance. Actual: 
                )

        )

)
```

This makes me believe I'm not providing input in the correct format but can't determine what is the expected format. Any help in this regard?

EDIT: If it helps, the following are parts of the WSDL that gets displayed when I open the $url in the browser

```
<wsdl:operation name="Assess">
   <wsdl:input message="typ:AssessRequest"/>
   <wsdl:output message="typ:AssessResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

---

```
<xsd:complexType name="AssessRequest">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>An assess-request contains an optional config node and a mandatory global-instance node.</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="config" type="AssessmentConfiguration" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Options that control how the data provided to the assess operation should be processed, and how the response should be constructed.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="global-instance" type="GlobalInstanceType">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Input data on which to perform the assessment, using the policy model deployed at the service URL</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: soapUI is a very good, free tool which allows you to test out services without writing any code (It does much more). Once you download it, start a new project by specifying the WSDL URL. It will create a default request which you can replace with your request. Send the request, examine the response. If the response is acceptable, you know your request is good. If not, your response is not in right format.

Comment: Thanks MikeC for the suggestion. I did use soapUI initially and I was getting response. So the service is good. What I'm not sure about is the format in which the input needs to be passed to the service

Answer (score 0):

Your statement "This makes me believe I'm not providing input in the correct format" threw me off. What you need at this point is a tutorial in using nuSOAP and PHP. SO is likely not the place for that. More like [PHP NuSOAP Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140189/PHP-NuSOAP-Tutorial) or [Working with PHP NuSOAP](http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/php/working-with-nusoap.php)